# Homebrew fails when upgrading VIM

Tags: vim, homebrew, upgrade

When I run `brew upgrade` on macOS Sierra, the operation fails. The only thing it's trying to upgrade is `vim 8.0.0550`. I've tried deleting the tar file and forcing a redownload of the upgrade but that hasn't helped. Here is the stacktrace—I can attach more of the log if necessary:

```
ld: library not found for -lruby.2.4.0
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [vim] Error 1
make: *** [first] Error 2
```

Edit: Since posting, a [thread on this bug](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/12323) has appeared on github. At time of writing, it's still not 100% clear what the problem is.

Comment: Hmm from a first glance I would say that a dependency (lruby) is missing causing clang (the C compiler) to fail.

Comment: Could also be that you never installed another Ruby version than the one preinstalled by macOS? Since I also had similar issues with Ruby dependencies when working with the Travis CI CLI interface.

Comment: I have ruby 2.4.0 installed—what exactly is `lruby`?

Comment: What's strange is vim previously upgraded fine (to 8.0.525), and I'm not sure what's changed on my system since then.

Comment: `-lruby.2.4.0` is a linker flag `-l` and an argument `ruby.2.4.0`. It is looking for `libruby.2.4.0.dylib` in the linker path. If it's expecting the brew version, then the path would probably be `/usr/local/lib/libruby.2.4.0.dylib`.

Comment: Thanks @DanLowe , how can I use this info to fix the error?

Comment: I do already have that file, but it's at `/Users/adc17/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/libruby.2.4.0.dylib`

Comment: You probably just want to install ruby in brew (it shouldn't interfere with your rvm, which is designed to ignore other rubies anyway). Then the linker will find the library it expects to find.

Comment: Thanks @DanLowe, I symlinked to the library from the brew directory you referenced, and that fixed the problem.

Comment: I've actually since been warned against this method, as apparently it will negate the work of rvm. Any other ideas for how to solve this?

Comment: It's not really a solution, but I've now switched from rvm to rbenv and the problem has disappeared. Looks like it's an rvm-specific issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came to this question because I was facing the same problem on my Mac OS Sierra.

I have brew and rvm and the brew vim install was failing with the linker error described in the question above. But, I did not want to switch to rbenv as suggested in the comments. I also was not sure about messing with symlinks as I tend to forget and delete the original files that were being linked :-)

The work around I tried was to temporarily switch to the Mac system Ruby install using the command

> rvm use system

Then do the brew upgrade of vim and once the install is complete revert back to the ruby that you want to use with rvm.

This worked for me - YMMV

Comment: Thanks @Nikhil, I've tried this with RVM and it also works for me. I think this is the simplest solution for those who don't want to switch to rbenv.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

1. Run `brew doctor`. This showed the following entry in the text:
   +

   > Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
   >   Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
   >   those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
   >
   > ruby
2. To fix run `brew link --overwrite ruby`
3. Now proceed to upgrade vim by running `brew upgrade vim`

I also recommend to fix other reported unlinked kegs.

Hope this helps. It worked pretty well for me.

Comment: `brew link --overwrite ruby` resolved it for me (but before I installed ruby 2.5.1)